# Can't access my Nodejs Express Server with socket.io (CORS)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, socket.io, cors

I am trying to use socket.io in order to send data between connected users.
Currently I am just using a localhost vue client and NodeJS express server but for some reason I am getting this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Od4xImE'
> from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

When I navigate to the link 'http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Od4xImE', it gives me back the following which seems to be okay:

> 0{"sid":"vbn04o2Bp2_RWhO_AAAX","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":20000,"maxPayload":1000000}

So the problem is something with the CORS. I can't seem to get it to work, and I've tried so many different things.

Here is my server:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server =http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(server);
const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080'
}));

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log("A user connected");

  socket.on("message", (data) => {
    console.log("Recieved message: ", data);
    io.emit("message", data);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("A user disconnected");
  });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello, this is the root route!');
});

const PORT = 3000;

server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

And here is my client:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import vuetify from "./plugins/vuetify";
import router from "../router";
import io from 'socket.io-client';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

Vue.prototype.$socket = socket;

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount("#app");
```

Comment: What is the value of this `const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;`?

Comment: it's 3000. PORT = 3000